# Comparing analytical Fourier transform with FFTs

Tags: numerical-methods, fourier-analysis, matlab, fourier-transform

This is related to my [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49130327/proving-fourier-transform-operation-in-python) on Stackoverflow.

From using the [tables on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Tables_of_important_Fourier_transforms) or Mathematica I can prove that the Fourier transform of function
$$f(t) = -i H(t) \exp(-(ia+b)t),$$
where $H$ is the Heaviside function, is
$$F(\omega) = \dfrac{\omega-a-ib}{(\omega-a)^2+b^2}.$$
This was performed using
$$F(\omega) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dt e^{-i\omega t} f(t) .$$

However if I try to calculate the Fourier transform numerically, either using Matlab or Python3, I get different results. [Cris Luengo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49142862) to my question shows graphically how the analytical and numerical results differ. The red line comes from Matlab's `fft` whereas the blue line is from $F(\omega)$ above.

[image]

Why don't the analytical and numerical approaches agree? Is it because of the FFT algorithm or something more subtle?